# Transcribing particular phrase in 1813 English will

Tags: palaeography, will

I have transcribed one of my ancestor's wills - it is from 1813 in Hereford, England. There is only one particular section that I can't figure out. It is 5 lines up from the bottom of the page I will attach and the sentence reads:

... I give to Elizabeth
Powis the sum of five pounds and further give to my daughter Ann
Prince and to my Grandson William Harris the sum of fifty five
pounds to be equally divided between them and my will and desire is
that the two sums of money which I have bequeathed to my Grandson
William Harris shall be placed out to interest till he shall arrive
to the age of twenty one years and the yearly interest arising from
the sum to be laid out ? ? ? for him at the discretion of
my Executor hereaftermentioned...

I know that "the sum to be laid out" is a particular phrase used in some wills and I think the word following it is "in" but I can't make out what the next two words are. I think there may be a double s in the next word (I have compared the letters with the rest of the will and the double s looks like two ffs but in the case of this word there is an extra loop so I'm not sure). I would be grateful for any help!

[image: Scan of 19th Century handwritten will]

Answer (score 6):

> the yearly interest arising from the sum to be laid out **in necessary uses** for him at the discretion of my Executor

The missing words "in necessary uses" really just means as needed to support his grandson's upbringing and other related expenses, giving the executor control over the exact timing of payments.

Comment: Thank you so much! That makes a lot of sense :)